# Lookup table in excel using EPPLUS

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Using [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), I have added 2 worksheets to an excel workbook like so

```
// add a new worksheet
ExcelWorksheet worksheetProduct = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Product");
worksheetProduct.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Producer";

// add a new worksheet
ExcelWorksheet worksheetProducer = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Producers");
//Add the headers
worksheetProducer.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Name";
worksheetProducer.Cells[1, 2].Value = "ID";
```

In the Product work sheet, I then add a Producer column with a drop down containing the names of the Producers, it was added as follows

```
var producerList = worksheetProduct.DataValidations.AddListValidation("A2");
producerList.Formula.ExcelFormula = "=ProducerList";
```

The user then fills in the spreadsheet and uploads it, I would like to get the ProducerId based on the value in the drop down, so in the Product sheet I can get the Producer Name easily enough,

```
string producerText = worksheetProduct.Cells[row, 1].Value.ToString();
```

How do I now query the Poducer worksheet to get the ID?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read your Producers sheet first and load it into a lookup-friendly object like a Dictionary!

Here are some links to get you started with dictionaries:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx
http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary